# CSS .Hover Image Loading Slow

Tags: css, hover, mousehover

I have a submit button that changes when the user hovers his mouse over it.  Right now the image is taking a while to load and you get a half second where there is white screen instead of the other button.  Is there anyway to improve this using just CSS and HTML or do I need to do some JS work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [sprite image](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites), and then toggle background position on hover. That ensures that the image being displayed on hover has already been downloaded.

Comment: although i have noticed a lapse in sprites too.

Comment: Hmmm. I have never seen that behavior.

Answer (score 2):

[CSS Sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

And load the css sprites when DOM is ready, this can sort of "preload" the image before user hovers on the submit button :)

Comment: how is this answer different from durilai's?

Comment: @pixeltocode : justification : demo link provided, and my advice on "preloading" the css sprites when DOM is ready to save loading time and improve usability.

Comment: and how is 'preloading' different from 'aleady been downloaded'??

Comment: @pixeltochode : all right, that's the story : I spent 2 mins searching through my bookmarks and tested the css sprite link before submit this answer,so that was why it was 2 minutes later than the above one. I mean no trying to gain a tick or anything, just feel this might be helpful to @Splashlin. If you feel this is a duplicate answer, that's fine. Can we end this questioning plz?